# How to contain a div within a div?

Tags: css

I have 2 columns, 50% and 50%
i want to contain the [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) on the left then a Message and a button on the right.
but i don't know how to contain the Slick Slider, please help.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGBEF.jpg)

The bottom part is the one I'm fixing, it should look like the one above

Here is my code:
section-events.jade:

```
section.events
    .flex.flex--center
        .col-50
            .single-item
                .item.item1 item 1
                .item.item2 item 2
                .item.item3 item 3
                .item.item4 item 4

        .col-50.flex.flex--center
            .col-1
                .desc-wrap
                    p.home-lead.outdented ...Current news and events...
                    a(href="").home-cta See All News
```

style.sass:

```
.flex
    display: flex

.flex--center
    justify-content: center

.col-1
width: 320px
padding: 0 10px
box-sizing: border-box

.col-50
width: 50% 

@media (max-width: 640px)

.col-1
    width: 100%

.col-50
    width: auto
```

section-events.sass

```
section.events
    background:
        image: url(../img/events-bg.jpg)
        position: center
        size: cover

    .home-lead
        color: white

    .home-sections &
        padding: 0

        @media (max-width: 640px)
            padding-bottom: 50px

    .col-1
        display: flex
        align-items: center

        @media (max-width: 640px)
            display: block

    .home-cta
        color: white
        background: #F06292

    .col-50
        .single-item
            width: 50%
            position: absolute

            .item
                width: 100%
                height: 100%
                text-align: center
                line-height: 300px
                color: white
                font-size: 30px

            .item1
                background:
                    image: url(../img/events-bg.jpg)
                    position: center
                    size: cover

            .item2
                background:
                    image: url(../img/academics-bg.jpg)
                    position: center
                    size: cover

            .item3
                background:
                    image: url(../img/about-bg.jpg)
                    position: center
                    size: cover

            .item4
                background:
                    image: url(../img/events-bg.jpg)
                    position: center
                    size: cover
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .col-1
  width: 100%
```

Should be  `50%` and everywhere else `.col-1` occurs.